# Need some reviews in PEAS descriptions

Tags: intelligent-agent, environment

**Here is the Question:**

Describe the PEAS descriptions for the following agents:

a) A grocery store scanner that digitally scans a fruit or vegetable and
identifies it.

b) A GPS system for an automobile. Assume that the destination has been
preprogrammed and that there is no ongoing interaction with the driver.
However, the agent might need to update the route if the driver misses a turn.

c) A credit card fraud detection agent that monitors an individual’s transactions
and reports suspicious activity.

d) A voice activated mobile-phone assistant

For each of the agents described above, categorize it with respect to the six dimensions
of task environments as described on pages 41-45 (Section 2.3.2 of AIMA). Be sure
that your choices accurately reflect the way you have specified your environment,
especially the sensors and actuators. Give a short justification for each property

Here is what i thinks that the answers of above questions might be this. Can you guyz correct me if i answered wrong at any point.
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what is "PEAS" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1):

PEAS stands for (Performance, Environment, Actuators and Sensors), when you are asked to give the peas of a AI then you should describe it as follows:
Example:
PEAS for refinery controller:
•   Performance measure: maximize purity, yield, safety
•   Environment: refinery, operators
•   Actuators: valves, pumps, heaters, displays
•   Sensors: temperature, pressure, chemical sensors
Please refer to the following link where I found precise information:

[http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~duygulu/Courses/CS461/Notes/Agents.pdf](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Eduygulu/Courses/CS461/Notes/Agents.pdf)